# Best to go with single api user or need to create multiple users

Tags: rest-api, integration, administration, apexrest

salesforce is allready integrated with serviceNow ..MiddleWare is SnapLogic , we created one API user in salesforce , Now we have new integration project salesforce is integrate with HRC system here also middleWare is snapLogic ...can i use old api user that allready in snapLogic, in this case for HRC integration? or go with diff new user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce automatically tracks the User that creates/last modifies/owns a record. For some applications this information is significant. There are then further features hinted at in this [User, Sharing, and Permission Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_users.htm) ERD (copy below) that are driven by that information that some applications may want to use.

If your application does not today, and will never in the future, need these capabilities then a single integration user might be the way to go. Cost is certainly a factor, because Salesforce is priced per user per month. But do check that your use complies with Salesforce licensing terms.

[image: ERD]

Comment: Any disadvantages with single user ? compare with multiple

Comment: @purna There are per-user limits, such as concurrent open query cursors. Overusing a single user may eventually lead to unusual errors. I agree with the core of this answer, though: for just two integrations, it's probably acceptable to use a single user, just be aware that there is an upper limit to the number of concurrent sessions you can have before you run into problems.

Comment: @sfdcfox Think those points are probably worth a separate answer...